# PDO update returns success, but doesn't update the database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PDO to update a column in a table. It runs fine, and `execute()` returns `1` (success). But, when I check the database the value in the `status` column hasn't changed.

```
/*
 * Add jobs to the beanstalkd queue
 */
foreach($jobs as $job) {

    $pheanstalk->useTube('scraper')->put(json_encode([
        'username' => $job['username'],
        'password' => $job['password'],
        'proxy'    => $job['proxy'],
        'gender'   => $job['gender'],
        'age'      => $job['age'],
        'device'   => $job['device']
    ]));

    /*
     * Update the row in the database and change its status to "queued"
     */
    try {
        $sql = "UPDATE cron_jobs SET status = :status WHERE id = :cid";
        $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindValue(":status", "queued");
        $sth->bindValue(":cid", $job['cid']);
        print $sth->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, $e->getTraceAsString());  
        exit;
    }    
}
```

Any ideas? It's not reaching the `catch` block, and no exceptions occur.

Comment: Double check your cid value. Make sure that $job['cid'] has the right value and that there is a corresponding row in the table. If there's no error and you're getting a success response from PDO, it likely means the update query executed fine and either updated the wrong row or updated 0 rows.

Comment: I've checked the values, they are present and correct.

Comment: Not in this case no. It's very confusing because the same query works when running it from the mysql shell using the same credentials, so the user has update privileges.

Comment: Fixed it, posted answer. Was a dumb error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. This:

```
$dbh->prepare($sql);
```

Should be:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
```

I had another query in the script above, I often reuse variable names. I totally forgot to add the variable. It's always the silly mistakes that catch you out the longest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use commit.

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();
//you code
$dbh->commit();
```

Check PDO docs. :)

Comment: How would that solve the problem? I am only making one transaction each time, and they do not depend on each other. It should work without the need for transaction.

Comment: Check database configuration. This problem is Commit Config.

Comment: The problem is solved and it is nothing related to what you are suggesting. Check my own answer.